# Why not redirect to the /login when accessDecision.decide() throw AccessDeniedException?

Tags: spring-security

I have a custom accessDecisionManager like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {

    @Override
    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes)
            throws AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {

        LogManager.getLogger("CustomAccessDecisionManager").info("decide invoke");

        if (configAttributes == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (configAttributes.size() <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        Iterator<ConfigAttribute> authorities = configAttributes.iterator();
        String needAuthority = null;

        while(authorities.hasNext()) {
            ConfigAttribute authority = authorities.next();

            if (authority == null || (needAuthority = authority.getAttribute()) == null) {
                continue;
            }

            LogManager.getLogger("CustomAccessDecisionManager").info("decide == " + needAuthority);

            for (GrantedAuthority ga : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
                if (needAuthority.equals(ga.getAuthority().trim())) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new AccessDeniedException("No Authority");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

It's work, and throw an AccessDeniedException, but the page show exception directly, why not jump to the login page?

I have add the custom securityInterceptor before ExceptionTranslationFilter:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(customFilterSecurityInterceptor(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should add your filter after `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will catch exception after it, and then decide what to.
2. There are two kinds of exceptions that `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will handle, `AuthenticationException` and `AccessDeniedException`.

`AuthenticationException` -- this will send to start authentication(e.g  redirect to login page);
`AccessDeniedException` -- this will send to `Access Denied Handler`(except anonymous, this will send to start Authentication).

So, If you want to redirect to loginPage, just throws the exception extend `Authentication`(Is that good ?)， or you can handle the `AccessDeniedException` in your access denied handler.